# how printf works internally.?

Tags: c, assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ function definitions without assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442966/c-c-function-definitions-without-assembly)

hi again,
I want to know how printf works internally...by internally I mean what **underlying system calls/ISRs** etc mechanism is used...and not about the variable argument list...

Reason:I am using FASM but there is little there for console i/o, I know I can use printf available from the c library(I don't know how but that's a different point)

thanks.

Comment: you can get it by looking into open source implementations

Comment: http://www.koders.com/c/fid4E0FA789459803C1E4369279B96E5C9B257941C8.aspx?s=printf#L7

Comment: similar to [Understanding the hardware of printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457656/understanding-the-hardware-of-printf)

Answer (score 7):

The `write(2)` system call is used with the file descriptor set to `STDOUT` (its value is 1).

To invoke a system call from assembly, the eax register has to hold the id of the system call (I think the particular number of `write()` is 3) and the rest of the registers (ebx, ecx, ...) have to contain the arguments. Then doing an `int 80h` will switch the control from your process to the kernel routine that handles system calls.

The above is platform-specific, but virtually all Unix-like operating systems work like that.

Comment: System call [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Typical_implementations) can also be architecture specific.  CISC architectures such as x86 support additional techniques such as SYSCALL/SYSENTER or SYSRET/SYSEXIT "fast" control transfer instructions designed to quickly transfer control without the overhead of an interrupt.