# How to output to console window without iostream in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, iostream, system-calls

I'm a beginner C++ programmer.I would like to know that *Is it possible to output to console windows without using iostream header file?*

the answer of the question is actually **Yes** ! but How?

Comment: A search for [console functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should probably turn something up.

Comment: Why? You can with `write`

Comment: You can use [c style I/O functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), but why?

Comment: Because i would like to know that how iostream does this?

Comment: @Amirreza - How deep do you wish to go. The Electric is generated by fission. This occurs because U235/U238 ... Uranium is produced by the stars

Comment: @EdHeal,I wish to go deep a little more :D . So until now i know that is call WinAPI,Is that true?

Comment: _"how iostream does this?"_ Most of the `std` implementations will use low level [`read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) functions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean that are these functions existed on all operating systems(Mac,Win,Linux)?

Comment: @Amirreza Yes, they are available on all POSIX API compliant systems. Windows is partly POSIX compliant, especially the I/O parts are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are all the c++ functions finally defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460614/how-are-all-the-c-functions-finally-defined)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Windows' Posix subsystem was removed in Windows Vista, I think it was. Anyway it was very incomplete. The phasing out began already in Windows NT 4.x with the introduction of Services for Unix (SFU). At one time it was a bit silly. You could install Microsoft's Interix-based SFU and get a very old g++ compiler, from Microsoft.

Comment: So how iostream reaches suitable API in linux,@Cheersandhth.-Alf says that POSIX API is removed!

Answer (score 2):

You can always delve down to the C library level, using e.g. `printf`.

If you don't want to use the standard library at all then you have to use platform-specific functionality. In Windows there are many layers here, much like the C++ versus C layers in the standard library. The highest Windows API layer is the `WriteFile` function, and below that, `WriteConsole`, then perhaps `WriteConsoleOutput`, so on, check it out.

Note that there are at least two open source projects to provide more reasonable console functionality in Windows, namely Console2 at SourceForge and mintty at Google Code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used console output in my question just for an example.I know that applications can call operating systems API to do something that they actually want and i also know that the functions are different(atleast in name) in different operating systems.But my main question is that How C,C++ library actually finds suitable API?

Comment: To get answers to a different question, ask that question. Tip: try to be very clear.