# How does printf work internally?

Tags: c, assembly, printf, standard-library

I am curious as to how `printf` works internally within Linux. I don't understand how it writes data to `STDOUT`.

After a bit of searching for the internals, I downloaded `glibc` and took a look at the source code:

```
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   int done;

   va_start (arg, format);
   done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
   va_end (arg);

   return done;
}
```

After finding this, I went deeper into the `vfprintf` function - but the file is about 2500 lines of unfamiliar C code. I'm looking for an explanation from 10,000 feet of how printf works with a computer's memory and output to display characters on screen.

If I were a piece of assembly code what would I have to do to accomplish the same task? Is it operating system dependent?

Comment: It all boils down to writing to a device (almost as if it was a file).  The device driver takes over and interprets the ASCII values and tells the monitor how to display them.  Same with disk, mice, etc.

Comment: no, he wants to understand vfprintf too, not just the underlying write. The other thread contains the rest, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking at the wrong layer. The logic in `vfprintf` is responsible for formatting its arguments and writing them through the underlying stdio functions, usually into a buffer in the `FILE` object it's targetting. The actual logic for getting this output to the file descriptor (or on other non-POSIX-like systems, the underlying device/file representation) is probably in `fwrite`, `fputc`, and/or some `__`-prefixed internal functions (perhaps `__overflow`).

Comment: Thank you - between this answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442966/c-c-function-definitions-without-assembly I have a better understanding of what's going on.